# Check page for modifications if the user browses away from page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tabs

I've have a primefaces web application, which consists of several tabs in which the user can enter and edit some data. If a user edits data and want to save this, he presses a save button and the data will be persisted to an database. If he want's to revert his entries he simply press the reset button.

Each tab is a own included .xhtml page.

Now we want to check, if the user navigates away with the menu or press the reset button, if there were made some changes and ask him if he really want to browse away without saving.

Do you have any suggestions?

Here the page of the tabs:

```
    <p:tabView id="tabView" 
        activeIndex="#{management.activeTabIndex}"
        rendered="#{management.dataFetched}"
        styleClass="tab-view">

        <p:ajax event="tabChange" update=":tabForm" />

        <p:tab id="firstTab" title="First">
            <p:panel id="firstPanel" styleClass="info-panel">
                <ui:include src="/home/test/infoHost.xhtml" />
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="secondTab" title="Second">
            <p:panel id="secondPanel" styleClass="info-panel">
                <ui:include src="/home/test/infoDb.xhtml" />
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="thirdTab" title="Third">
            <p:panel id="thirdPanel" styleClass="info-panel">
                <ui:include src="/home/test/infoSt.xhtml" />
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write jQuery function when tab is clicked and bind it to tabs. In this function I would get the content of data, create `<p:remoteCommand>` which invoke backing bean function. As a parameter I would pass data from jQuery function and in backing bean compare it with the value of field storing data. If these things differ call a dialog from backing bean "Are you sure...".

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml